# Resonance of a non-straight pipe

Tags: resonance

Simple question, but I can't find any answer around.

If a pipe turns, aka is not straight, the length of the pipe (in order to calculate the resonance frequency) is given by the length of the imaginary line connecting the centers of the circular section of the pipe, by an imaginary string of zero width that connects the two extreme of the pipe, or by which other measure?

For a straight pipe is easy, but I can't find any information on what happens when it bends.

Silly question for the standard here, but I don't know where else to ask

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you measure the length of a pipe for the purpose of calculating the resonance frequency. That would be my question. For a straight pioe is trivial, but for a non-straight pipe there are several possible answers, but the resonance is only one of course